# Send mail with Shopping Cart Items

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

I used Below code for send mail if customer enter Unsupport pincode. It's working fine:

```
<?php

class Webkul_Mpperproductshipping_Model_Carrier_LocalDelivery extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
{
    /*  Use group alias */
    protected $_code = 'mpperproductshipping';

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        $postCode = $request->getDestPostcode();

        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $name = $customer->getName();
        $email = $customer->getEmail();
        $restrictedCodes = [
            110001,
            110002,

        ]; //restricted values. they can come from anywhere
        if (!in_array($postCode, $restrictedCodes)) {
            $body = 'Hi admin, '
                . 'I am ' . $name . ($email) . ' I try to Place Order with this Pincode ' . $postCode . ' But I cant able to place order please check with it';
            $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
            $mail->setToName($name);
            $mail->setToEmail('mymail@gmail.com');
            $mail->setBody($body);


            $mail->setSubject('Not Support Pincode');
            $mail->setFromEmail('domain.com');
            $mail->setFromName($name);
            $mail->setType('html');// You can use 'html' or 'text'

            try {
                $mail->send();
                //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');
                //$this->_redirect('');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
                // $this->_redirect('');
            }

            return false;

        }
```

I try to send a mail with shopping cart item also with this code:

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();

}
```

But it show only one items not all items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$productName = array();
$skus = array();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $productName[] = $item->getProduct()->getName();
    $skus[] = $item->getProduct()->getSku()
}

$productNames = implode(', ', $productName);
$productSkus = implode(', ', $skus); // or do something else...
```